# Get file path of the highlighted files using nautilus script

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, nautilus

I want to get file paths of the files that are selected. I have being try this for the entire day now with no luck.

[image]

For example by clicking on the script "filename.py", I would like to get that path of the highlighted directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the documentation of [Nautilus scripts](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NautilusScriptsHowto) you can get the paths to selected files using the environment variable `NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS`. In Python you can get its value using [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.environ) and then later you can use [`os.path`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#module-os.path)'s functions to do operations on the paths:

```
import os
paths = os.environ['NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS'].splitlines()
for p in paths:
    if os.path.isdir(p):
        print p
```